# tidyr::separate() throwing an unexpected error

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I know I'm not alone in having problems with separate() but the last hour of searching StackOverflow has not resulted in an answer to the error I'm getting.

Data:

```
structure(list(geoid = c("41001", "41001", "41001", "41001", 
"41001", "41001", "41001", "41001", "41001", "41001", "41001", 
"41001", "41001", "41001", "41001", "41001", "41001", "41001", 
"41001", "41001", "41001", "41001", "41001", "41001", "41001", 
"41001", "41001", "41001", "41001", "41001", "41001", "41001", 
"41001", "41001", "41001", "41001", "41061", "41061", "41061", 
"41061", "41061", "41061", "41061", "41061", "41061", "41061", 
"41061", "41061", "41061", "41061", "41061", "41061", "41061", 
"41061", "41061", "41061", "41061", "41061", "41061", "41061", 
"41061", "41061", "41061", "41061", "41061", "41061", "41061", 
"41061", "41061", "41061", "41061", "41061"), name = c("Baker County, Oregon", 
"Baker County, Oregon", "Baker County, Oregon", "Baker County, Oregon", 
"Baker County, Oregon", "Baker County, Oregon", "Baker County, Oregon", 
"Baker County, Oregon", "Baker County, Oregon", "Baker County, Oregon", 
"Baker County, Oregon", "Baker County, Oregon", "Baker County, Oregon", 
"Baker County, Oregon", "Baker County, Oregon", "Baker County, Oregon", 
"Baker County, Oregon", "Baker County, Oregon", "Baker County, Oregon", 
"Baker County, Oregon", "Baker County, Oregon", "Baker County, Oregon", 
"Baker County, Oregon", "Baker County, Oregon", "Baker County, Oregon", 
"Baker County, Oregon", "Baker County, Oregon", "Baker County, Oregon", 
"Baker County, Oregon", "Baker County, Oregon", "Baker County, Oregon", 
"Baker County, Oregon", "Baker County, Oregon", "Baker County, Oregon", 
"Baker County, Oregon", "Baker County, Oregon", "Union County, Oregon", 
"Union County, Oregon", "Union County, Oregon", "Union County, Oregon", 
"Union County, Oregon", "Union County, Oregon", "Union County, Oregon", 
"Union County, Oregon", "Union County, Oregon", "Union County, Oregon", 
"Union County, Oregon", "Union County, Oregon", "Union County, Oregon", 
"Union County, Oregon", "Union County, Oregon", "Union County, Oregon", 
"Union County, Oregon", "Union County, Oregon", "Union County, Oregon", 
"Union County, Oregon", "Union County, Oregon", "Union County, Oregon", 
"Union County, Oregon", "Union County, Oregon", "Union County, Oregon", 
"Union County, Oregon", "Union County, Oregon", "Union County, Oregon", 
"Union County, Oregon", "Union County, Oregon", "Union County, Oregon", 
"Union County, Oregon", "Union County, Oregon", "Union County, Oregon", 
"Union County, Oregon", "Union County, Oregon"), value = c(426, 
496, 480, 412, 397, 453, 466, 504, 396, 424, 452, 570, 641, 651, 
564, 417, 272, 204, 396, 450, 457, 340, 327, 366, 438, 458, 362, 
390, 447, 620, 690, 667, 538, 435, 259, 259, 801, 840, 875, 962, 
1060, 821, 778, 836, 743, 642, 638, 731, 880, 871, 718, 457, 
339, 303, 701, 830, 808, 920, 1052, 810, 731, 814, 676, 660, 
636, 818, 1006, 865, 712, 558, 373, 570), agegroup = c("0 to 4", 
"5 to 9", "10 to 14", "15 to 19", "20 to 24", "25 to 29", "30 to 34", 
"35 to 39", "40 to 44", "45 to 49", "50 to 54", "55 to 59", "60 to 64", 
"65 to 69", "70 to 74", "75 to 79", "80 to 84", "85 years and", 
"0 to 4", "5 to 9", "10 to 14", "15 to 19", "20 to 24", "25 to 29", 
"30 to 34", "35 to 39", "40 to 44", "45 to 49", "50 to 54", "55 to 59", 
"60 to 64", "65 to 69", "70 to 74", "75 to 79", "80 to 84", "85 years and", 
"0 to 4", "5 to 9", "10 to 14", "15 to 19", "20 to 24", "25 to 29", 
"30 to 34", "35 to 39", "40 to 44", "45 to 49", "50 to 54", "55 to 59", 
"60 to 64", "65 to 69", "70 to 74", "75 to 79", "80 to 84", "85 years and", 
"0 to 4", "5 to 9", "10 to 14", "15 to 19", "20 to 24", "25 to 29", 
"30 to 34", "35 to 39", "40 to 44", "45 to 49", "50 to 54", "55 to 59", 
"60 to 64", "65 to 69", "70 to 74", "75 to 79", "80 to 84", "85 years and"
), sex = c("Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", 
"Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", 
"Male", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", 
"Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", 
"Male", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female")), row.names = c(NA, 
-72L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

The code that works (that produced the above data):

```
get_estimates(
  geography = "county",
  product = "characteristics",
  breakdown = c("AGEGROUP", "SEX"),
  breakdown_labels = TRUE,
  state = "OR",
  county = str_to_title(county_list)
) |>
  clean_names() |>
  filter(sex %in% c("Male", "Female")) |>
  filter(str_detect(agegroup, "^Age")) |>
  mutate(agegroup = str_replace(agegroup, "^\\w+\\s+(.*)\\s+\\w+", '\\1'))
```

The next line that is throwing an error:

```
|>
  mutate(
    agegroup = case_when(agegroup == "85 years and" ~ "85+ years",
                         TRUE ~ agegroup),
    name = separate(col = name, 
                    into = c("name"), 
                    sep = "\\s")
  )
```

The error:

```
Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `name = separate(col = name, into = c("name"), sep = "\\s")`.
Caused by error in `UseMethod()`:
! no applicable method for 'separate' applied to an object of class "character"
Backtrace:
 1. dplyr::mutate(...)
 6. tidyr::separate(col = name, into = c("name"), sep = "\\s")
```

Is there just something obvious that I'm not seeing? I'm using `separate()` on a character column! I'm just attempting to capture the first word of that column and discard the rest! Any and all insight would be very welcome.

**Edit**

Solved my current problem with

```
 |>
  mutate(
    agegroup = case_when(agegroup == "85 years and" ~ "85+ years",
                         TRUE ~ agegroup), 
    name = word(name, 1, -3)
  )
```

but would still really very much like to know why `separate()` isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are using `separate` within `mutate`.
`separate` allows to define the colnames.
I have used 3 names as the split would lead to 3 new columns in order to avoid any warning messages. If you would just use one `into=c("a")` this would give you the desired output but also some warnings that there are more splits.
You can of course also deselect the unwanted cols: `select(-c(b,c))`.

```r
df |> 
  mutate(agegroup = case_when(agegroup == "85 years and" ~ "85+ years",
                              TRUE ~ agegroup)) |> 
  separate(name, into=c("a", "b", "c"), sep=" ")
#> # A tibble: 72 × 7
#>    geoid a     b       c      value agegroup sex  
#>    <chr> <chr> <chr>   <chr>  <dbl> <chr>    <chr>
#>  1 41001 Baker County, Oregon   426 0 to 4   Male 
#>  2 41001 Baker County, Oregon   496 5 to 9   Male 
#>  3 41001 Baker County, Oregon   480 10 to 14 Male 
#>  4 41001 Baker County, Oregon   412 15 to 19 Male 
#>  5 41001 Baker County, Oregon   397 20 to 24 Male 
#>  6 41001 Baker County, Oregon   453 25 to 29 Male 
#>  7 41001 Baker County, Oregon   466 30 to 34 Male 
#>  8 41001 Baker County, Oregon   504 35 to 39 Male 
#>  9 41001 Baker County, Oregon   396 40 to 44 Male 
#> 10 41001 Baker County, Oregon   424 45 to 49 Male 
#> # … with 62 more rows
```

Comment: I knew it was going to be something basic like this. That's what I get for coding late. <sigh> Thank you for your patient and gracious explanation.